# Is there a function in the base MATLAB that returns a printable representation of a variable for use in eval or the console?

Tags: matlab

For example, if I have this matrix stored in `mat`:

```
0.9058    0.1270    0.9134
0.6324    0.0975    0.2785
```

is there some function `func(mat)` that will return a string I could pass into `eval` or use on the console to redeclare that variable, e.g.:

```
[0.9058,0.1270,0.9134;0.6324,0.0975,0.2785]
```

I haven't come up with anything searching the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/index.html), but I find functions like this in other languages, e.g. Python's `repr`, very convenient during interactive/console use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: The original answer was totally bogus, here's a better:

How about `mat2str(mat)`?

http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/format.html

> str = mat2str(A) converts matrix A into a string. This string is
>   suitable for input to the eval function such that eval(str) produces
>   the original matrix to within 15 digits of precision.

Comment: `pretty` doesn't do what my original question asked, but nevertheless, I added more information. I'm not trying to make pretty output. I'm trying to make output that can be passed into `eval` or reused on the console. Pretty printing is completely different. Also, it's only available in the Symbolic Math Toolbox, and it doesn't take standard matrices as an argument (you need to use `sym`, which isn't relevant to what I'm asking). Try `a = magic(5); pretty(a)`.

Comment: Yes I completely misread the your question, sorry about that. I edited my answer with another solution.

Comment: `mat2str` is it! Brilliant. Maybe get rid of the references to `pretty` so people seeing this question in the future don't get confused.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution is [MATRIX2M](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8933-matrix2m) from the FileExchange. It can work with 3D matrices as well, that `mat2str` cannot. Although the output is not as pretty.

```
>> x = rand([1 2 2]);
>> Matrix2M('x')
ans =
x = zeros(1,2,2);
x(1,1,1) = 0.16218230819324275;
x(1,2,1) = 0.79428454068390697;
x(1,1,2) = 0.31121504204480488;
x(1,2,2) = 0.52853313550621273;

>> class(ans)
ans =
char
```